# How to resolve a variable number of promises in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, q

I'm working on a function (called by an express.js route) to merge event info in a database with its Facebook counterpart and return it as an array of event objects.

I am having trouble with the asynchronous nature of node.js and resolving a variable number of promises within a foreach loop before returning the whole object. I've tried numerous different methods of rearranging my code (callbacks, counters, promises, etc.), but I have not been successful in solving this problem, and I would really like to know why. I suspect it has to do with variables being overwritten in the foreach loop, but I'm not sure how to solve that.

**I am looking for three things:**

1. What am I not grasping conceptually that is needed to solve this problem?
2. How would I figure this out or debug this in the future?
3. How do I fix my code to make it work?

---

Here is my function:

```
function mergeEvents(req, res, next, events){

console.log("Merge Events");

var dfd = q.defer();

ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next).then(function(auth){
    var iEvent, event;
    var promises = [];

    if (auth){
        console.log("authenticated!");
        console.log("auth token: " + ACCESS_TOKEN);

        for (iEvent in events){
            event = events[iEvent];

            var promise = q.defer();
            promises.push(promise);

            https.get('https://graph.facebook.com/' + event.fb_id + '?access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN, function(response) {
                var str = '';
                response.on('data', function(chunk){
                    str += chunk;
                });

                response.on('end', function(){
                    var fb_event = JSON.parse(str);
                    event.dataValues.fb = fb_event;
                    promise.resolve(event);
                });
            });

            if (promises.length == events.length){
                console.log("last run through");
                q.all(promises).then(function(results){
                    console.log("all promises completed?");
                    console.log(results[0]); //OUTPUT BELOW
                    //more code in here... but promises haven't resolved
                    //...
                    dfd.resolve(events);
                });
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.log("Not authenticated. Redirecting to main page.");
        dfd.resolve(events);
    }
});

return dfd.promise;

}
```

While I am trying to get a JSON object, it returns an unresolved promise on console.log(results[0]):

```
{ promise: [object Object],
  resolve: [Function],
  fulfill: [Function],
  reject: [Function],
  notify: [Function] }
```

Code references I have viewed:

- https://github.com/kriskowal/q
- https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference
- https://strongloop.com/strongblog/how-to-compose-node-js-promises-with-q/
- http://thejsguy.com/javascript/node.js/2014/06/27/JavaScript-Flow-Control.html

Oh, and here's my function for a single event fb/db merge that works, so you can compare:

```
function mergeEvent(req, res, next, event){
console.log("Merge Event");

var dfd = q.defer();

ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next).then(function(auth){
    if (auth){
        console.log("authenticated!");
        console.log("auth token: " + ACCESS_TOKEN);
        https.get('https://graph.facebook.com/' + event.fb_id + '?access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN, function(response) {
            var str = '';
            response.on('data', function(chunk){
                str += chunk;
            });

            response.on('end', function(){
                var fb_event = JSON.parse(str);
                event.dataValues.fb = fb_event;
                dfd.resolve(event);
            });
        });
    }else{
        console.log("not authenticated. redirecting to main page");
        dfd.resolve(event);
    }
});

return dfd.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

```
var promise = q.defer();
promises.push(promise);
```

`q.defer()` does not return a promise. It returns a [*deferred*](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#qdefer).

```
var result = q.defer();
promises.push(result.promise);
```

Naming variables correctly is important, you didn't see the mistake because you chose improper variable names.

---

That being said...

- Avoid `for .. in`. Arrays have `.forEach()` or `.map()`.
- Instead of checking `if (promises.length == events.length)`, move that part out of the loop.
- Your function is pretty long and could use a little refactoring.
- And of course, don't call your deferred objects "deferred" or your promise objects "promise". That's not descriptive.
- Read through [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) (let it sink in, it takes some time)

Here's what I would use.

```
var q = require('q');
var qHttp = require("q-io/http"); // -> https://github.com/kriskowal/q-io

var FB = {
    // collect other FB API methods here, maybe transform into module
    graph: function (id) {
        var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' + id + '?access_token=' + ACCESS_TOKEN;
        return qHttp.read(url).then(function (data) {
            return JSON.parse(data.toString());
        });
    }
};

function mergeEvents(req, res, next, events) {
    return ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next).then(function (auth) {
        if (!auth) return q.reject("Not authenticated.");

        return q.all(events.map(function (event) {
            return FB.graph(event.fb_id).then(function (data) {
                event.dataValues.fb = data;
                return event;
            });
        }).then(function (results) {
            //more code in here...
        }));
    });
}
```

Note: If you wrote `ensureAuthenticated`, modify it to reject directly and on its own instead of resolving with a falsy `auth` value that you need to check every time you use it. The line `if (!auth) ...` could be removed after that.

Also, the `//more code in here...` part that deals with the "enhanced" events should *probably* live outside of `mergeEvents`.

Comment: Thank you! As a beginner with promises, this was very helpful, as were the resources :)